# How to accurately segment the basic shaped elements in a hand drawn sketch?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to segment the basic shaped elements in a hand-drawn sketch using the `cv2.findContours` - external contours detection method. But the problem is the accuracy of some segmented elements are not 100% achieved. Inner contours are also considered as a separated element. As well, adjacent elements which are drawn in small-sized are also detected as one element. It would be really helpful if someone can suggest a solution in order to achieve the accuracy of the segmented elements?

Here is the sample sketch.
[image: hand drawn sketch]

Here is the output.
[image]

This image shows the result of the external contour detection. But it also has detected the inner contours and segmented them as separated elements.

Here is the code.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os

#Read image
img = cv.imread('img/img.jpeg')
#cv.imshow('Img', img)

# resized function
def rescaleImg(img,scale_percent=60):
        height, width, channel = img.shape

        print('original height: ', height)
        print('original width:  ', width)
        print('original channel:', channel)
        if height > 200 or width > 500:
            width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
            height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
            dimension = (width, height)
            resized = cv.resize(img, dimension, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)
            return resized
        else:
            resized=img
            return resized

#resize image
resized = rescaleImg(img)
#cv.imshow('Rescaled', resized)

#convert to gray
gray= cv.cvtColor(resized, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv.imshow('gray',gray)

#reduce noice by median blur
median_blur = cv.medianBlur(gray,5,5)
#cv.imshow('median blur',median_blur)

#edge cascade
canny= cv.Canny(gray,30,200)
cv.imshow('canny',canny)

#dialate image
dilated=cv.dilate(canny,(5,5),iterations=3)
cv.imshow('dilated',dilated)

eroded = cv.erode(dilated,(1,1),iterations=3)
#cv.imshow('eroded',eroded)

#convert into threshold
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(eroded,125,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
#cv.imshow("Thresh", thresh)

#contour detection
contours,hierarchy = cv.findContours(dilated,cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print('Numbers of contours found=' + str(len(contours)))
#print(contours)

#draw all contours
cont= cv.drawContours(resized, contours, -1, (0,255,0),3)
cv.imshow('External Contours', cont)
 
height, width, channels = resized.shape


#croping image
data=[]
idx =0
for index, cont in enumerate(contours):
    idx += 1
    (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(cont)
    #print( x, y, w, h)
    x = x - 2
    y = y - 2
    w = w + 4
    h = h + 4

    rect = cv.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
   
    crop_img = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    new = cv.imwrite('img/croped_img/'+ str(idx) + '.jpg', crop_img)
    
#cv.imshow('cropped',img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can u also share `img.jpeg` ? So we can try ur code

Comment: sure. I added the image

Comment: Please show your result and explain where it did not work. You should be able to get external contours easily enough.

Comment: When i tried the code, it seems u are able to detect all the contours accurately. Where is the point causes problem ?